# Decreasing Column size in heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap

[image]

I got this Rplot using heatmap function in R.

Now I just wanted to decrease column width so that i can see image at one glance. As you can see this plot need to be zoomed to check what labels it contains, so I need to reduce width of columns of this plot. Is there any solution to this?

Please help...
UPDATED POST: 
FOLLOWING IS CODE USED

`    myCol <- c("blue", "green", "yellow", "orange", "brown","red")

```
 myBreaks <- c(0, 100, 350, 500, 1000, 10000,3500000)

 Heatmap<-heatmap.2(Heatmap_input, dendrogram ='row',
      Colv=FALSE, col=myCol, 
      breaks=myBreaks,
      key=FALSE, keysize=0.5, symkey=FALSE, density.info='none',
      trace='none', 
       sepwidth=0.05,
      scale="none",cexRow=0.5,cexCol=1,
      labCol = colnames(Heatmap_input),                 
      hclustfun=function(c){hclust(c, method='mcquitty')},
      lmat=rbind( c(0, 3), c(2,1), c(0,4) ), lhei=c(0.25, 4, 0.25 ))`
```

Comment: It's helpful if you can post the code you used to generate this plot so we can see what settings you used. Also, how did you turn it into an image? Did you write to a graphics device like pdf() or png()? Did you explicitly set the width/height?

Comment: hm <- heatmap.2(wcMatrix_new1, scale="none", Rowv=NA, Colv=NA,
                col = myCol, ## using your colors
                breaks = myBreaks, ## using your breaks
                dendrogram = "none",  ## to suppress warnings
                margins=c(5,5), cexRow=0.5, cexCol=1.0, key=FALSE,
                trace="none")

Comment: If I save this plot as pdf and want to see heatmap, I cant see whole heatmap in single glance. I have to zoom it again and go to left or righ which is quite headache. Any solutions to this??